# How to perform relative importance analysis on ordinal logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, weights, importance

[relative importance analysis](https://www.displayr.com/nps-driver-analysis-with-displayr/)
there is an package called "flipRegression" from github.com which can perform relative analysis/ relative weights to analyze the importance of each brand attribute in relation to the others.
I cannot download this package from github, is there any other way to do this analysis?

Comment: what do you get when you run `require(devtools)`
`install_github("Displayr/flipRegression", dependencies = NA)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a method published in the academic literature extending relative weights analysis to ordered logistic regression.  That is, it is unclear how it is implemented in `{displayr}`; I suspect the method uses linear regression to decompose the $R^2$ however.

That said, there is a method using the `dominance_analysis()` function from the parameters `{parameters}` package that is designed to work with the proportional odds model/ordered logit model.

For example, the below uses the `datasets::mtcars` data to get a ordered logit model and then conduct a dominance analysis on it (based on an approach discussed by Luchman, 2014).

```
library(MASS)

mtcars |> 
   transform(gear = as.ordered(gear)) |> 
   polr(gear ~ mpg + qsec + wt, data = _) |> 
   parameters::dominance_analysis()

# Dominance Analysis Results

Model R2 Value:  0.530 

General Dominance Statistics

Parameter      | General Dominance | Percent | Ranks |   Subset
---------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept: 3|4 |                   |         |       | constant
Intercept: 4|5 |                   |         |       | constant
mpg            |             0.177 |   0.335 |     2 |      mpg
qsec           |             0.075 |   0.142 |     3 |     qsec
wt             |             0.277 |   0.523 |     1 |       wt

Conditional Dominance Statistics

Subset | IVs: 1 | IVs: 2 | IVs: 3
---------------------------------
mpg    |  0.296 |  0.233 |  0.004
qsec   |  0.021 |  0.131 |  0.074
wt     |  0.440 |  0.333 |  0.058

Complete Dominance Designations

Subset | < mpg | < qsec | < wt
------------------------------
mpg    |       |        | TRUE
qsec   |       |        |     
wt     | FALSE |        |
```

Depending on how large your model is, you might consider using the `sets` argument to group variables to speed along runtime.

*Reference*

Luchman, J. N. (2014). Relative importance analysis with multicategory dependent variables: An extension and review of best practices. *Organizational Research Methods, 17(4)*, 452-471.

Comment: Your 2014 paper is really excellent and also has a great literature survey of pseudo $R^2$ measures.  I’m glad to know about it.  I was also glad to see our (Peterson & Harrell 1990) work referenced.  A less comprehensive but simpler measure of relative importance may be found  at https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/validate.html#sec-val-rev .  This is based on projecting a categorical dependent variable model onto a linear model.  One advantage is that it admits bootstrap or Bayesian uncertainty intervals for relative importance.

Comment: Many thanks @FrankHarrell for the kind words. The dominance approach does struggle to scale up and is rather computationally involved to bootstrap.  See the advantage of a streamlined method for interval estimates and appreciate the pointer to the linked methodology.